# Function prints none instead of printing what I want it to print in decorators in Python

Tags: python, decorator

I am studying on decorators in Python. I was trying to use the decorators with arguments.  I'm having a problem with the decorators. I defined two inner function in the default decorator function. It returns none when I use it as below:

```
def prefix(write: bool = False):
    def thread(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            t1 = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            t1.start()
            if write:
                print("write parameter is true.")
        return wrapper
    return thread


@prefix(write=True)
def something(x):
    return x + x


print(something(5))
```

As you see, I defined two different functions named prefix and something. If the write parameter is true, it prints the string. But something function is printing "None" instead of printing 5 + 5.

What's wrong?

Comment: Why does it run the function in another thread?

Comment: @Barmar I was just trying it. There's no reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your `wrapper()` function doesn't have a return statement, so it will always return `None`.

Furthermore, how would you expect it to print `5 + 5` (or rather, the result thereof) when that may not have been computed yet, considering you're starting a new thread to do that and never do anything with the return value of `func` at all?

IOW, if we expand your example a bit:

```
import time
from threading import Thread


def prefix(write: bool = False):
    def thread(func):  # <- this function replaces `something`
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            t1 = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            t1.start()
            if write:
                print("write parameter is true.")
            return "hernekeitto"

        return wrapper

    return thread


@prefix(write=True)
def something(x):
    print("Computing, computing...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Hmm, hmm, hmm...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Okay, got it!")
    return x + x


value = something(9)
print("The value is:", value)
```

This will print out

```
Computing, computing...
write parameter is true.
The value is: hernekeitto
Hmm, hmm, hmm...
Okay, got it!
```

As you can see, the thread's first `print()` happens first, then the `write` print, then the value print, and then the rest of what happens in the thread. And as you can see, we only know what `x + x` is *after* "Okay, got it!", so there's no way you could have returned that out of `wrapper()` where `"hernekeitto"` is returned.

See [futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) (or the equivalent JavaScript concept promises) for a "value that's not yet ready":

```
import time
from concurrent.futures import Future
from threading import Thread


def in_future(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        fut = Future()

        def func_wrapper():
            # Wraps the threaded function to resolve the future.
            try:
                fut.set_result(func(*args, **kwargs))
            except Exception as e:
                fut.set_exception(e)

        t1 = Thread(target=func_wrapper)
        t1.start()
        return fut

    return wrapper


@in_future
def something(x):
    print("Computing, computing...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Hmm, hmm, hmm...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Okay, got it!")
    return x + x


value_fut = something(9)
print("The value is:", value_fut)
print("Waiting for it to be done...")
print("Here it is!", value_fut.result())
```

This prints out

```
Computing, computing...
The value is: <Future at 0x... state=pending>
Waiting for it to be done...
Hmm, hmm, hmm...
Okay, got it!
Here it is! 18
```

so you can see the future is just a "box" where you'll need to wait for the actual value to be done (or an error to occur getting it).

Normally you'd use `futures` with the executors in `concurrent`, but the above is an example of how to do it by hand.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. Can you explain in a little more detail?

Comment: You're starting a new thread to run the function, but there is no way to get the return value of that call: for one, because threads don't have that facility by themselves, and secondly because that value may not exist by the time you would be printing it, because the thread may not have run to completion.

Comment: As far as I understand, you mean there is no way to get the return value from another thread?

Comment: There is no "return value" for a thread, but see my edited answer; what you may want is a `Future`.

Comment: I got you. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Deezwend Happy to help. Please see my edit which shows how to use Futures too.